# Subset row based on first letter of each row

Tags: r, dplyr

```
dput(abc)
structure(list(Comparison = structure(1:15, .Label = c("C1_C2 ", 
"C1_C3 ", "C1_C4 ", "C1_C5 ", "C1_C6 ", "C2_C3 ", "C2_C4 ", "C2_C5 ", 
"C2_C6 ", "C3_C4 ", "C3_C5 ", "C4_C5 ", "C4_C6 ", "C5_C6 ", "C6_C5 "
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is my data-frame

```
Comparison
1      C1_C2 
2      C1_C3 
3      C1_C4 
4      C1_C5 
5      C1_C6 
6      C2_C3 
7      C2_C4 
8      C2_C5 
9      C2_C6 
10     C3_C4 
11     C3_C5 
12     C4_C5 
13     C4_C6 
14     C5_C6 
15     C6_C5
```

So when i do for C1 and subset it works fine like I will get C1_C2,C1_C3,C1_C4, C1_C5, C1_C6. This works fine for C1

But when i do grep for C2 ,this will also find row which are C1_C2 as well which i dont want.I want only which starts with C2_C3,C2_C4,C2_C5,C2_C6. Same goes with C3,C3,C5,C6.

My code to filter

```
C1  <- comparsion %>% filter(str_detect(Comparison,"C1")).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for base R alternative you can choose `startsWith`, Also note that your Comparision column is in factor, so `startsWith` doesn't work on factors , you need to wrap it inside `as.character` to make it work, you may change it for other columns like C1, C2 etc if you are only looking for character starting with C1, C2 etc :

```
data[startsWith(as.character(data$Comparison), 'C1'),,drop=FALSE]
```

You can also work with dplyr using startsWith, like below:

```
data %>% 
  filter(startsWith(as.character(Comparison), 'C1'))
```

Comment: same with your answer "when im accepting your answer the tick turns green but again it turns grey im not sure what is happening "

Comment: @PesKchan, Only one answer can be accepted, that is why this is happening. You may want to accept the both the answer but its not possible. Please mark Ronak's answer as accepted, as he was the first one who answered it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `^` to indicate start of the string.

```
subset(abc, grepl('^C1', Comparison))

#  Comparison
#1     C1_C2 
#2     C1_C3 
#3     C1_C4 
#4     C1_C5 
#5     C1_C6
```

With C2 :

```
subset(abc, grepl('^C2', Comparison))

#  Comparison
#6     C2_C3 
#7     C2_C4 
#8     C2_C5 
#9     C2_C6
```

---

In `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

abc %>% filter(str_detect(Comparison, '^C2'))
```

Comment: when im accepting your answer the tick turns green but again it turns grey im not sure what is happening

Comment: @PesKchan You can accept only one answer per post but upvote more than 1.

Comment: "ou can accept only one answer per post but upvote more than 1" okay i didn't know that